# Split a column based on a character in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table as shown below on BigQuery

```
Name | Score
Tim  | 63 > 89 > 90
James| 67 > 44
```

I want to split the `Score` column into `N` separate columns where N is the maximum score length in the entire table. I would like the table to be as follow.

```
Name| Score_1 | Score_2 | Score_3
Tim | 63      | 89      | 90
James| 67     | 44      | 0 or NA
```

I tried the `Split` command but I end up doing a new row for each Name-Score combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For BigQuery Standard SQL

Below is simple case and assumes you know in advance the expected max score length (3 in below example)

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.your_table` AS (
  SELECT 'Tim' name, '63 > 89 > 90' score UNION ALL
  SELECT 'James', '67 > 44' 
)
SELECT 
  name, 
  score[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] AS score_1,
  score[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] AS score_2,
  score[SAFE_OFFSET(2)] AS score_3
FROM (
  SELECT name, SPLIT(score, ' > ') score
  FROM `project.dataset.your_table`
)
```

with result

```sql
Row name    score_1 score_2 score_3  
1   Tim     63      89      90       
2   James   67      44      null
```

Of course above approach means  - if you have many scores  - like 10 or 20 or more  - you will need to add respective number of extra lines like below

```sql
  score[SAFE_OFFSET(20)] AS score_21
```

So, above gives you what you wanted from schema of output point of view

At the same time, below makes more sense to me and in most practical cases is better and most optimal  :

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.your_table` AS (
  SELECT 'Tim' name, '63 > 89 > 90' score UNION ALL
  SELECT 'James', '67 > 44' 
)
SELECT name, score
FROM `project.dataset.your_table`, UNNEST(SPLIT(score, ' > ')) score
```

with result

```sql
Row name    score    
1   Tim     63   
2   Tim     89   
3   Tim     90   
4   James   67   
5   James   44
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried the second before I posted this question but I still wanted a way to do the first method. This helps although we need to hard code the columns.

Comment: there is a relatively easy way to actually write another sql that will make this for you. try to search in my old answers - if you will not find but still want to know  - post new specific question and I will answer when have time :o)

Comment: You mean creating a row for each combination and then pivoting it?

Comment: yes. in case of quite a number of column this can help a lot :o)

Comment: I have your answer! That was my only hope if I hadn't gotten a reply to this question :)

Comment: great. :o) glad you did search first :o)